# Clickable svg function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, radio-button

I have svg circles with radio buttons under each one, i want to control the radio buttons behavior based on the svg click, when i click on the first svg the radio button under it gets checked, when i click on the next one the first one should be unchecked and the second should be checked and so on, here is what i tried so far:

```js
$(".circle").click(function(){
    $(this).next().prop('checked',true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg height="100" width="100">
  <circle class="circle" cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
</svg>
<input type="radio" name="check">

<svg height="100" width="100">
  <circle class="circle" cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="green" />
</svg>
<input type="radio" name="check">

<svg height="100" width="100">
  <circle class="circle" cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="blue" />
</svg>
<input type="radio" name="check">
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add `name` attribute for each radio button with the same value.

see code snippet:

```js
$("svg").click(function(){
    $(this).next().prop('checked', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg height="100" width="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
</svg>
<input type="radio" name="rd">

<svg height="100" width="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="green" />
</svg>
<input type="radio" name="rd">

<svg height="100" width="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="blue" />
</svg>
<input type="radio" name="rd">
```

Comment: Can you check the updated version of my question please?

Comment: @JudyM. you are linking the event to the circle which is inside svg, so next() will not work in this case, you need to get the parent() then get next(), see my update